# How to append NSString wiht number?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm new in Cocoa.

I have NSString - (e.g)  MUSIC . I want to add some new NSString in Array,
And want to check something like this

if MUSIC already contained in Array, add Music_1 , after Music_2  and so on.

So I need to be able read that integer from NSString, and append it +1 .

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
NSString *newString = [myString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%i", myInteger]];
```

if myString is "music", newString will be "music_1" or whatever myInteger is.

EDIT: I seem to have gotten the opposite meaning from the other answer provided. Can you maybe clarify what it is you are asking exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Check it out:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"123", @"qqq", nil];
NSString *myString = @"MUSIC";
NSInteger counter = 0;
if ([array containsObject:myString]){
    NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d", myString, ++counter];
    [array addObject:newString];
}
else
    [array addObject:myString];
```

Answer (score 1):

For checking duplicate element in Array you can use `-containsObject:` method.

```
[myArray containsObject:myobject];
```

If you have very big array keep an `NSMutableSet` alongside the array.Check the set for the existence of the item before adding to the array. If it's already in the set, don't add it. If not, add it to both.
If you want unique objects and don't care about insertion order, then don't use the array at all, just use the Set. `NSMutableSet` is a more efficient container.
For reading integer from `NSString` you can use `intValue` method.

```
[myString intValue];
```

For appending string with number you can use `- (NSString *)stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)aString` or `- (NSString *)stringByAppendingFormat:(NSString *)format ...` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you convert a string to an int

```
NSString *myStringContainingInt = @"5";
int myInt = [myStringContainingInt intValue];
myInt += 1;
// So on...
```