# Calculator label string displaying

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I'm new to Objective-C and trying to make a calculator. My problem is I can't add the new number when button is pressed to the string no matter what I use (I tried methods appendString/Format and stringByAppendingString/Format).

Inputting numbers. I do the same for every other numbers:

`- (IBAction)btn9:(id)sender {`

`[self tabbedNumber:9];`
`}`

Declare the variable:

```
@property NSString *labelString;
```

Getting the number function:

```
-(void)tabbedNumber:(int)num{
    NSString *lblStr = [[NSString alloc]init];

   lblStr = [lblStr stringByAppendingString:[@(num) stringValue]];
   self.labelString = lblStr;

   [self updateText];
}
```

Displaying on calculator with a label calLabel:

```
- (void)updateText{
    self.calLabel.text = self.labelString;
```

Best Anwser by @pavelTerziyski:

You keep lblStr = [lblStr stringByAppendingString:[@(num) stringValue]] in the function but the creation of the variable must be in the view didLoad - (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; self.lblStr = [NSString new]; }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append NSString wiht number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822704/how-to-append-nsstring-wiht-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you get the (int)num - because i tried your code with this and it worked perfectly fine

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

NSString *lblStr = [[NSString alloc]init];

lblStr = [lblStr stringByAppendingString:sender.titleLabel.text];
self.labelString = lblStr;

[self updateText];
}

- (void)updateText{

self.numberLabel.text = self.labelString;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I have edited my question with a number button method which i use for every other numbers. My problem is every time another number is pressed, the labelString is replaced with that number but not all numbers that were pressed. Please help me out! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: For what i understand the problem is the numbers are not keeped in the string after you type and this is caused because you create the                    NSString *lblStr = [[NSString alloc]init]; in the function and everytime it creates new string with @"". So just create the lblStr in the ViewDidLoad method and u're good to go :) hope it helps you

Comment: That's totally my problem at the moment. At this line `lblStr = [lblStr stringByAppendingString:[@(num) stringValue]];` I used the variable 'num' to pass it into the String in my method. Can you help me to pass that into the viewDidLoad?

Comment: You keep lblStr = [lblStr stringByAppendingString:[@(num) stringValue]] in the function but the creation of the variable must be in the view didLoad      - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.lblStr = [NSString new];
}

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot man. I have been struggling with this for quite a long time. Thank you thank you.

Comment: No problem dont forget to add +1 to the comment :D

Comment: I did +1 to the comment but don't know how to +1 to yours. How can I do that? I added your answer in my post.

Comment: Arrow up left of the comment you like is the +1 :)

Comment: Oh I did that. But my reputation is below 15 so It's not showing. I did it anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
- (IBAction)tabbedNumber:(UIButton *)sender{

     self.labelString.text = [self.labelString.text stringByAppendingString:sender.titleLabel.text];

}
```

With this you can add any button's title label text to your label string.
But you should connect number buttons to this method.

if you want to update label with another method try this

```
- (IBAction)tabbedNumber:(UIButton *)sender{

     [self updateText:sender.titleLabel.text];

}

- (void)updateText:(NSString *)tappedNumberString{

     self.labelString.text = [self.labelString.text stringByAppendingString:tappedNumberString]; 

}
```

Don't forget to connect `tabbedNumber` method to number Buttons.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping me. I tried this before. It works fine for the updating the calculator label but not for calculating purpose.

Comment: It will keep the 0 in front of all the numbers which are pressed because it's a text. I have edited my question with a number button method which i use for every other numbers so that I can perform my calculation. I use the `[@(num) stringvalue]` to convert the number to string but every time another number is pressed, the labelString is replaced with that number but not all numbers that were pressed. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Appending something to a new created string is not very useful.

You need to append the integer (as text) to the property `labelString` which seems to hold the actual value of the label.

```
-(void)tabbedNumber:(int)num{
   self.labelString = [self.labelString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", num];
   [self updateText];
}
```